# need to explode a text/csv file uploaded from form

Tags: php, file, upload

When i use an html form to post a file, how do i address that file's contents in php?

will this work?

```
$data = $_POST['file'];
$pre = explode(";;;", $data);
```

the file is a text file btw

**UPDATE**
the csv is field enclosed with ::: and lines terminated by ;;;. How can i load this into a variable without breaking the php script, which is what is happening now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

umm you can do

```
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$pre = explode(";;;", $data);
```

something like that should work

Comment: sorry .. yes just fixed it :)

Comment: its saying the file is empty.

Comment: ah i am getting lazy .. sorry about that :) ... it should be $_FILES not $_FILE .. try the code now

Comment: this has to be worst ever line of code i have written .. 3 mistakes in one line .. wow!

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not work. You'll need to save the file locally, first, and open the file with something like file_get_contents(). Please read the [PHP Tutorial on File Uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)